# Was Urahara's Bankai ever revealed or hinted at?

Tags: bleach

I used to watch and read Bleach before, but I stopped following the series after the defeat of Aizen.

Urahara's Bankai is a mystery to me, and since I'm no longer updated, I don't know if there's more to tell on Urahara's abilities.

Has there been an update on what we know about Urahara since Aizen's defeat?

Comment: As far as I remember it was never revealed: Urahara just said that his bankai was not suited for training (Urahara told that to Renji while he was training with Ichigo)

Comment: It is offical as noted by the answer by louis, Bleach chapter 664, released today, revealed his bankai on the last page, so we know what it looks like, but not its powers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In chapter 664, Urahara was finally forced to use his Bankai. This happens on the final page of the chapter.

It summons a giant person:

[image: Picture of last page from chapter 664 of Bleach]

In Chapter 665,

> Urahara reveals that his Bankai has the power to restructure anything it touches: 
>  [image: Picture from Bleach Chapter 665]

As can be seen in the above picture where his eyes are being stitched up, Urahara is also able to utilize this ability on himself to heal wounds. Considering the ability of his Bankai, it's easy to understand why he didn't use it to train Chad when Chad needed to fight against a Bankai.

Comment: Answer changed to this one. Please update this when the next chapter goes out! :) 

Thanks.

Comment: Will do! @MarkGabriel

Comment: so it's like unohana bankai on steroid ?

Comment: @NamikazeSheena I actually think it looks eerily like Unohana in one of the panels.  And what the heck her bankai did is still rather unclear.

Answer (score 10):

As of yet, Urahara's Bankai has never been revealed. We know that he is capable of it, but he has never actually used it on-panel.

Back when Ichigo was still working to attain his Bankai (Chapter 132), Yoruichi informed Ichigo that Urahara gained his Bankai using the same training method, and did it in three days.

Later (Chapter 224) Sado comes to him for training. Urahara tells Sado that he needs to train against a Bankai in order to improve. He then assigns Sado to train with Renji, saying that his own Bankai was not suitable for training. This implies that his Bankai is either absurdly lethal, or may not be a combat-focused weapon (like how Unohana's Shikai is a flying ray medevac thing).

Comment: I remember when the Espada first arrive and Orihime and Chad fought them Urahara used his Zanpakutō and when he said "Sing, Benihime" it could dissipate the fired Cero at point blank range which as Love states, is far more dangerous than one fired from a distance, i think that's a testament on just how powerful Benihime can be